# Can't return a dictionary from my function

Tags: python, dictionary, return

I am getting an invalid syntax error

```
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 root@collabnet:/home/projects/twitterBot# python twitterBot2.py
 File "twitterBot2.py", line 58
 return screenNames
```

when returning a dictionary from this function:

```
def getUserName(lookupIds):
     l = len(lookupIds) # length of list to process
     i = 0 #setting up increment for while loop 
     screenNames = {}#output dictionary
     count = 0 #count of total numbers processed
     print 'fetching usernames'
     while i < l:
         toGet = []
         toAppend = []
         if l - count > 100:#blocks off in chunks of 100
             for m  in range (0,100):
                toGet.append(lookupIds[count])
                count = count + 1
                print toGet
         else:#handles the remainder 
             print 'last run'
             r = l - count 
             print screenNames
             for k  in range (0,r):#takes the remainder of the numbers 
                 toGet.append(lookupIds[count])
                 count = count + 1
             i = l   # kills loop

         toAppend = api.lookup_users(user_ids=toGet)
         print toAppend
         screenNames.append(zip(toGet, toAppend)

         #creates a dictionary screenNames{user_Ids, screen_Names}

     #This logic structure breaks up the list of numbers in chunks of 100 or their
     #Remainder and addes them into a dictionary with their count number as the 
     #index value   
     #print str(len(toGet)), 'screen names correlated'
     return screenNames
```

I am running the function like so:

```
 toPrint = {}#Testing Only
 print "users following", userid 
 toPrint = getUserName(followingids)#Testing Only
```

I have tried commenting out and just printing `screenNames`and I still get the same error except on the print statement instead. I am pretty sure I am running the return right thanks for the look.

Comment: Is the indentation you provided the same as in your code?

Comment: Also, ``screenNames`` is defined as a set/dict (it's ambiguous because you use an empty ``{}`` initializer), yet you're adding elements to it with ``append``, which is not valid for either a ``dict`` or a ``set``.

Comment: @aruisdante: It is definitely a dict, there is no ambiguity there. You cannot define an empty set that way. The comment on that line even makes it clear what the OP was expecting to happen on that line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Oh you're right, I forgot that Python doesn't allow empty-set literals for exactly the purpose of resolving said ambiguity ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a closing parenthesis on a preceding line:

```
screenNames.append(zip(toGet, toAppend)
#                 ^   ^               ^^?
#                 |   \---- closed ---/|
#                 \----- not closed ---/
```

You'll have another problem here, as `screenNames` is a *`dict`* object, not a list, and has no `.append()` method. If you wanted to update the dictionary with key-value pairs, use `update()` instead:

```
screenNames.update(zip(toGet, toAppend))
```

Comment: Although it's going to fail with an ``AttributeError`` anyway since ``screenNames`` is a ``set/dict`` and thus doesn't have an ``append``